Based on Offset value need to move the column value in SQL
Fiscal Week                              Quantity      Current_quantity
2024011                                    1000            0
2024012                                    2000            1000
2024013                                      0             2000
2024014                                     3000           0
2024015                                     0              3000

Offset = 1
I need help on How to achieve the above scenario
example if offset = 1 then the Current_quantity column should move by 1 based upon the Quantity column . For Fiscalweek 2024011 Quantity 1000 Current_quantity 0 , FiscalWeek 2024012 Quantity 2000 Current_quantity 1000. Since 1000 was the Quantity for fiscalweek 2024011 this became the current_quantity for fiscalweek 2024012.
Offset value can be anything between 0 - 8 .
Fiscal Week                              Quantity      Current_quantity
2024011                                    1000            0
2024012                                    2000            0
2024013                                      0             1000
2024014                                     3000           2000
2024015                                     0              0

For offset = 2
If offset is 2 then Current_Quantity for 2024013 will be 1000 and so on.
Offset is a column from another table . I am joining the table with offset table for getting offset value.
I tried the below query
SELECT
    FiscalWeek,
    Quantity,
    LAG(Quantity, Offset) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek) AS Current_quantity
FROM
    YourTableName
ORDER BY
    FiscalWeek;

but getting error function LAG needs to be constant, found 'OFFSET' in SNOWFLAKE

MySQL <> SQL Server

What's the database? MySQL or SQL Server?

In standard SQL (so it does not matter is it is MySQL or SQL Server) you can do this with a SELF-JOIN. (Which is pretty basic SQL)

This sounds kinda strange. What is the purpose of this dynamic offsetting?

"In snowflake"? That's neither MySQL or SQL Server.

Why did you remove the tag: [tag:snowflake-cloud-data-platform]  (see: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78426543/10 ) also the [tag:sql] says "...and a tag for the DBMS implementation:"   Please edit the tags to make it clear which environment you are using, and what the problem is besides this standard SQL question.  Please also specify WHERE the offset is defined in this SQL.

If you have a fixed limit of different offsets then you can use the CHOOSE function in SQL Server, the ELT function in MySQL, or the DECODE function in Snowflake.
SELECT
    FiscalWeek,
    Quantity,
    CHOOSE(Offset + 1,
      Quantity,
      LAG(Quantity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      LAG(Quantity, 2) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      LAG(Quantity, 3) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      LAG(Quantity, 4) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      LAG(Quantity, 5) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      LAG(Quantity, 6) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      LAG(Quantity, 7) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      LAG(Quantity, 8) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek)
    ) AS Current_quantity
FROM
    YourTableName
ORDER BY
    FiscalWeek;

Or
SELECT
    FiscalWeek,
    Quantity,
    DECODE(Offset,
      0, Quantity,
      1, LAG(Quantity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      2, LAG(Quantity, 2) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      3, LAG(Quantity, 3) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      4, LAG(Quantity, 4) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      5, LAG(Quantity, 5) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      6, LAG(Quantity, 6) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      7, LAG(Quantity, 7) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek),
      8, LAG(Quantity, 8) OVER (ORDER BY FiscalWeek)
    ) AS Current_quantity
FROM
    YourTableName
ORDER BY
    FiscalWeek;


i believe the offset is not a fixed number but the query works for fixed number. If the offset is not a fixed number then in that case  is there any other way

No you'd need a lateral self-join like the other answer

Can you help how the self join will work in query

See the other answer below.

With an offset of 0:
select m1.Fiscal, m1.Quantity, COALESCE(m2.Quantity,0) as Current_quantity 
from mytable m1 
left join mytable m2 on m1.Fiscal = m2.Fiscal;

with an offset of 1:
select m1.Fiscal, m1.Quantity, COALESCE(m2.Quantity,0) as Current_quantity 
from mytable m1 
left join mytable m2 on m1.Fiscal = m2.Fiscal+1;

see: DBFIDDLE which is using SQLite, which is NOT snowflake, but because this is very standard SQL it should work in snowflake too.
